# How to make Rmarkdown website using one .rmd file as template for multiple pages instead of one .rmd for each page?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I find rmarkdown sites interesting, but I would like to change from most example I have seen and I haven't found something yet.

I try to make a repoducible example:

folder struture:

```
project_folder
\_ _site.yml
\_ index.rmd
\_ script.R
\_ templates
   \_pages.rmd
```

I yml file alows to make the structure: I would like to have a website with the following categories (this an example of my _site.yml):

```
name: "website"
navbar:
  title: "website"
  left:
  - text: "global info"
    href: index.html
  - text: "species"
    menu:
        - text: "all species result"
          href: all.html
        - text: "---------"
        - text: "versicolor"
          href: versicolor_1.html
        - text: "setosa"
          href: setosa.html
```

then an index.rmd (here just a title in order to keep the example simple).

```
---
title: Some stuff
---
```

a template page like page.rmd in a template folder (very simple as well but it uses a parameter.

```
---
params:
  data_set:
title: "Region results"
---

hist(param$dataset$Sepal.Length)
```

and a "script" like, to render the site and then all pages except index.

```
markdown::render_site()

# import data
species = c("versicolor", "setosa")

# filter data and render page
for (i in 1:nrow(species)){
data_filtered <- dplyr::filter(iris, species == species[i])
rmarkdown::render("templates/page.rmd.Rmd", params = list(
  data_set = data_filtered,
output_file = paste0("../_site/", pages$species[i], ".html"))
}
```

Right now, I don't get the header on top of my html as I am not using the common structure....

I could also use another option (R based) if you have ideas. shiny isn't the best option.

Thank you!

Comment: One way would be to use parameters in the single page, and render it many times with different values for those parameters.  Another way would be to use Shiny and generate the pages at display time.

Comment: I am able to generate the page with a loop. But I cannot add the nav menu...

Comment: It's not clear from your post exactly what you have tried.  You should put together an example showing something that generates a full site, and others could try it and see if there's a way to modify it to include the nav menu.

Comment: I tried to be more specific about the example.